# Differentiating touches based on first or second

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, multi-touch

I'm trying to implement 2 distinct touch based behaviours. The first behaviour's logic is like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    moveViewTo(touchLocation) //moves my view to touchLocation
}
```

Now, for my second behaviour, I want to rotate the view based on where I have my finger on the screen. For this, I tried this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    rotateViewTo(touchLocation) //rotates my view to face touchLocation
}
```

Now, I want these two distinct behaviours to work concurrently. In particular, I want the first touch to change the position of the view, and the second touch to rotate the view.

Rotating is possible only if there are two touches in the view, and changes direction based on the second touch.

Is there any way to differentiate which of the touches are first and which are second? I can't find a way to differentiate from the `touches: Set<NSObject>` because by nature `Set` is an unordered collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only option is to store your first touch as a var. My swift isn't strong enough to write out the code for you but here are the steps.

1. Loop through your touches instead of just grabbing the first one.
2. Check if there is a firstTouch (your var for tracking first touch)
3. If there isn't a firstTouch assign the first touch and do your position logic
4. If there is a first touch check to see if each touch is the firstTouch. If it isn't then do your rotation logic.
5. On touches ended and canceled loop through each touch. If it is the firstTouch set your var to nil.

Sorry I can't write all the code out for you, but hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I did try something like that:
  
 1. Declared optional variable firstTouch: `var firstTouch: UITouch?`  
 2. In `touchesBegan`, store firstTouch: `firstTouch = touches.first as! UITouch`  
 3. In `touchesMoved`, do `println(firstTouch)`.  
  
For some reason, all my println statements said firstTouch was nil.

Comment: Did you verify it is getting set in touches began right after you set it?

Comment: Your logic works, my attempt earlier must have been faulty. Thank you very much.